# Jquery inArray always returns -1 in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problem with Jquery `inArray`.

```
//Get selected devices
selectedDevices = $('.selectDevices').val();
console.log(selectedDevices);

//If nothing selected, do nothing
if(selectedDevices == null || selectedDevices == ""){}

    //Else remove devices not selected
    else{ 
        //Loop thru table rows with class "enhet"
        $.each( $('td.enhet'), function() {

        thisDevice = $('.enhet').text();

        var found = $.inArray(thisDevice, selectedDevices);

        console.log(found);

        if (found > -1) {
            console.log(thisDevice);
        }
        else {
            console.log('nope');
        }


    })
}
```

Console.log(selectedDevices) give:
`["GulAvformning", "RosaAvformning"]`

Console.log(found) give: (everytime!!)
`-1`

Console.log(thisDevice) give:
``

Console.log('nope') give:
`nope`

Even if `thisdevice`exists in `selectedDevices` i get the else case.
What am i missing?

`selectedDevices` is an array. I checked it by: console.log(selectedDevices[1]); And it gave me one of the devices.

Comment: It doesn't work because both are strings.

Comment: `thisDevice = $('.enhet').text();` what is the value of `thisDevice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `each()` method to the elements and then use `$(this)` to identify the current element:

```
selectedDevices = $('.selectDevices').val();
console.log(selectedDevices);

//If nothing selected, do nothing
if(selectedDevices == null || selectedDevices == ""){}

//Else remove devices not selected
else{ 
  //Loop thru table rows with class "enhet"
  $('td.enhet').each(  function() {

    thisDevice = $(this).text(); // use $(this) here

    var found = $.inArray(thisDevice, selectedDevices);

    console.log(found);

    if (found > -1) {
      console.log(thisDevice);
    }
    else {
      console.log('nope');
    }


  })
}
```

Comment: Yes of corse, that was my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Well, my pleasure, check this answer as correct when you can make it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
thisDevice = $(this).text();
```

Instead of:

```
thisDevice = $('.enhet').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating but not selecting the iterator. Change your lines to this:
...

```
$.each( $('td.enhet'), function(i) {

        thisDevice = $('td.enhet').eq(i).text();
```

...

Comment: better to use the element itself returned within the each callback...otherwise you are searching the DOM each iteration to look for that same element. DOM searches are expensive

Comment: I agree. I was not sure with "this".

Comment: Use `$('td.enhet').each(...` and `this` is current element

Comment: I know. but I wasn't sure of it, never tried, so I didnt use "this". *I stand corrected*

Answer (score 0):

If `console.log(selectedDevices)` gives `["GulAvformning", "RosaAvformning"]`, and `console.log(thisDevice)` gives `""`, then `$.inArray(thisDevice, selectedDevices)` will return `-1`, since there's no `""` in `["GulAvformning", "RosaAvformning"]`. See [Marcos Pérez Gude's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35432435/1064325) for more info about how to properly get the correct value for `thisDevice`.